# Temporary Housing for Recursion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, recursion

Here is a simple multiplication recursive function.

```
public static int Mult(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return x + Mult(x, y - 1);
    }
}
```

Every time the function is returned and added to itself...

But until the final function returns with concatenation, where is this in memory and how come this quasi storage isn't visible in Visual Studio?

Just wondering if the Depth of the Thread represents some mysterious stack this **int** is temporarily living in?

```
Thread  Depth
[19260] [0] Line 21
[19260] [1] Line 14
...
```

Comment: Aside, I think if you pass the accumulation into the recursive call instead of accumulating after, your function will be tail-call optimized, which may provide a better answer to your question.

Comment: Oh, and that depth is the stack frame depth, not thread depth.

Comment: Actually it is visible in the call stack window. You will also see (because the recursion is not tail optimized) that the memory used by your application increases.

Comment: Parameters and return values like these are on the stack/in registers.

Comment: On a side note your method doesn't work if `y` is negative.  In fact if it is negative it's going to cause a stack overflow exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method calls exist in the call stack and the value in a registry. You can see a bit more information about the call stack in Visual Studio by opening a separate window (Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack). In VS 2013, you can access [$ReturnValue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) to see function return values, but this doesn't seem to work for me in VS2015.

You can right click the call stack window to see the values of each call, for example:[image: Callstack]

Comment: thanks plusone....i guess you can only see its footprints...where is it in memory though?

Comment: @Pinch if you have VS2013 you can see a bit more into the registers by using `$ReturnValue` in the watch / immediate window - see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

It doesn't seem to work for me in VS2015 though.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!